# server version where do I go to from command line interface prompt (DOS-type screen)

Tags: boot, command-line, server

help I am new to Linux/Ubuntu.

I installed the server edition on a micro server instead of Windows home server as used on my other one. After 3 attempts it finally installed.

However all I get at boot up time is a DOS type screen. I log in as requested and after a few lines of obscure text it just sits with an equally obscure and user unfriendly prompt. no help, no other prompt. I installed the grub boot loader but nothing else loads except this unfriendly dos style prompt.

Before I wipe the whole thing off the disk and look elsewhere could someone give a quickie idea of where I go from here.

All I need is a fairly straightforward file server that can be set up with users/shares etc.

Comment: Ubuntu Server doesn't have a GUI by default. It is command line only. If you want a GUI you'll have to install one.

Comment: You can add a graphical user interface, of which there are many: GNOME, KDE, xfce, LDXE, and the list goes on... none of which will materially improve the task of turning a newly installed Ubuntu Server machine into a Samba server.  Did you specify Samba and ssh during the server install process? Which version did you install; 12.04, 13.10, other? http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-a-linux-file-server-using-samba and https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html will be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

First I would like to welcome you to the world of Linux, once you start to get the hang of it you'll wonder how you ever lived without it.

As you installed the server edition you have a minimal installation, this gets the system running, but it is not very useful at this point.

To install software you will need to run `sudo apt-get install <package-name>` and then aptitude (the package manager) will do the rest. If you don't know the name of the package, you can always search for it using `apt-cache search <search-term>`.

To share files with your other machines (I'm guessing they are Windows) you need to install `samba` and get it up and running; it manages all of the connections to windows network shares (and more, if you should ever need it!)

Comment: thank you for your help  `I'll give that a try. its been a little while since last using Linux and that was a Suse desk top install  with full GUI so Im a bit rusty. Thought it about time to get back!

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu Server edition is intended for users who have experience with the command line.

I suggest you install the Ubuntu Desktop edition, which will provide you with all the features of the Server edition and allow you to do all of the same things.

There is a lot of documentation online about setting up a file server, and K7AAY included some links in the comments above.

Comment: thank you for your help  `I'll give that a try. its been a while since last using Linux and that was the Suse desk top install  with full GUI so Im a bit rusty. Thought it about time to get back into the Linux world. Really appreciate the kind help I am getting to help me get up and going again

Answer (score 0):

What you've described would most easily be available using the [desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) version of Ubuntu.  However, from your current installation of Ubuntu server, you can just install a [GUI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#Can_I_add_a_.22graphical_user_interface.22_.28GUI.29_to_a_server.3F) and [samba](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html).  You can do this from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Samba allows you to easily connect with Windows computers.  Ubuntu has a built-in function to share files though.  So, depending on what you want to do, you may not need Samba.  To share a folder in Ubuntu:

```
right-click the folder you want to share
select Properties
click the "Share" tab
select the "Share this folder" checkbox
```

Comment: thank you very much indeed for your kind help-  Im getting back into Linux after an absence. Ill give this a try